# Chat functionality in web application using XMPP and Openfire

Tags: xmpp, openfire, web-chat

I want to create chat functionality in my web application using XMPP and Openfire.. I have integrated converse js but I haven't found file attachment so any one let me know another best option using XMPP and openfire??

Comment: You could use [Strophe.js](http://strophe.im/strophejs/) a JS library for XMPP messaging. Instead if you wanted a web client already done check [Candy](http://candy-chat.github.io/candy/)

Comment: Thanks,
http-bind call is rejected while i m trying this.. and i have change all neccessary for http-bind.
i have created now domain for root directory but still not getting response..
if you have any demo using stroph.js then share it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very simple chat demo written in **jQuery** + **[StropheJS](http://strophe.im/strophejs/)**:

http://plnkr.co/edit/EhQHDsYpDhrECmaaIlZO

You have to deploy your own Openfire and adapt the followin code lines according to your configuration:

```
var server = 'mydomain.com';
var BOSH_SERVICE = 'http://127.0.0.1:7070/http-bind/';
var ROOM = 'prova@conference.' + server;
```

...

```
$('#jid').get(0).value = "pippo@mydomain.com";
$('#pass').get(0).value = "pippo";
```