# how to implement messaging or chat in cordova

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm going to create one app using cordova. I want to implement messaging or chat in cordova. I had tried  to find out [plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/plugins/?platforms=cordova-android%2Ccordova-ios),but didnt get for message.

Please help me if you know.

Comment: A possible answer to a broad question ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510219/chat-functionality-in-web-application-using-xmpp-and-openfire/34524981#34524981 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34453122/how-can-i-implement-chat-application-using-ionic-frame-work/34456138#34456138

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented chat in cordova by using `quickblox` server. It offers javascript SDK to implement chat. For more details [www.quickblox.com](http://www.quickblox.com)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to try [ConnectyCube](https://connectycube.com/)

They have SDKs and code samples for chat & messaging for Cordova/PhoneGap and other platforms

- Getting started https://developers.connectycube.com/js/
- Javascript SDK for chat & messaging guide https://developers.connectycube.com/js/messaging
- Code samples https://developers.connectycube.com/js/code-samples
- Cordova Chat code sample https://developers.connectycube.com/js/code-samples-chat-cordova